# copying the contents of a directory from Downloads to /etc

Tags: command-line, directory, copy, cp

I want to copy the contents of a folder `colors` from `~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master` to `/etc/vim/colors`. I tried this as instructed:

```
cp colors/* ~/etc/.vim/colors
```

But I am getting the error:

```
cp: target ‘/home/advenio/etc/.vim/colors’ is not a directory
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: First, are you sure you have an `etc` folder in your **Home** (`/home/advenio`)? Normally there isn't one there. Second, if your destination is `/etc`, then are you sure the vim folder has a dot in front of it?

Comment: Post the output of `[-d /home/advenio/etc/.vim/colors ] && echo "dir" || echo "not dir"`

Comment: You said, i want to copy from `~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master` then why do you try `cp colors/* ~/etc/.vim/colors`?

Comment: @user68186 Ok you were correct abut it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj actually I wan to copy the contents of colors in the vim/color dir

Comment: still it was unclear.Post the full path(for both source and destination)

Comment: Robin just run `mkdir -p ~/etc/.vim/colors && cp -rt ~/etc/.vim/colors ~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master/colors/*` You can [check my answer below](http://askubuntu.com/a/433292/212123) for more..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` refers to the home directory (in your case `/home/advenio/`). The place you want to copy it to is `/etc/vim/colors`

Try the command `sudo cp ~/Downloads/path_to_colors/colors/* /etc/vim/colors`

Comment: he will need sudo for copying into /etc ;)

Comment: I tried so, but still getting this error:
`cp: target ‘/etc/.vim/colors’ is not a directory
`.

Comment: Ok I had to remove `.` from `.vim` but now getting this error:
`cp: cannot stat ‘colors/*’: No such file or directory
`.

Comment: `colors` needs to be in your working directory. I don't know the full path, but if you do something along the lines of `cp ~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master/colors/* /etc/vim/colors` it should work fine. Bear in mind that that's a guess since I don't know your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/vim/colors && sudo cp ~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes*/colors/* /etc/vim/colors
```

Comment: I am getting an error:
`cp: cannot stat ‘colors/*’: No such file or directory
`

Comment: I fixed the command but make sure that you downloaded/cloned vim-colorschemes in ~/Download

Answer (score 0):

The command for copying a directory including all of its contents is:

```
me@linuxbox:~$ cp -R location_of_source_directory location_of_destination_directory
```

This command will create the destination directory at the new location.

For example, here I copied a folder from one destination to another destination. I used `cd` and `ls` to make sure the files were copied and didn't exist before.

[image: Copying a whole directory using terminal]

By the way, as you are trying to copy the folder to `/etc/...` you need to use `sudo` like:

```
me@linuxbox:~$ sudo cp -R location_of_source_directory location_of_destination_directory
```

Because that location is owned by root and you don't have permission to add/remove files/folders in there.

Answer (score 0):

When copying folders using the `cp` tool, use the recursive option. This copies the contents of the `colors` folder:

```
sudo cp  ~/Downloads/colors/* /etc/vim/
```

or copy the entire folder

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/colors/ /etc/vim/
```

where the `~` sign represents the home directory.

By the way it's not `.vim` but `vim`.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the target directory (here `~/etc/.vim/colors`) exists.

If it does not, create it with:

```
mkdir -p ~/etc/.vim/colors
```

To copy the contents of a source directory to some other location:

```
cp -rvt destination-directory source-directory/*
```

(this will copy all contents, both files and directories within `source-directory` to `destination-directory`.)

```
cp -vt destination-directory source-directory/*
```

(this will copy the files within `source-directory` to `destination-directory`.)

**Example:**

```
cp -rvt ~/etc/.vim/colors ~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master/colors/*
```

Here, the **contents of** `~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master/colors` **directory will be copied** to `~/etc/.vim/colors`.

If you want to copy the source-directory itself use:

```
cp -rvt destination-directory source-directory
```

(where `v` in `-rvt` is for verbose output, `r` for recursive used when copying directories, `t` to specify the destination.)

**Example:**

```
cp -rvt ~/etc/.vim/colors ~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master/colors
```

Here, the **source** `~/Downloads/vim-colorschemes-master/colors` **directory will be copied** to `~/etc/.vim/colors`.

Comment: it seems the correct location was `/etc/vim/colors` (the `.` was the whole problem I think)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to copy a folder in Ubuntu terminal.

At the upper most part of your terminal window you will know what user or directory you are.

Note: you won't be able to run the `cp` command if you are in the wrong directory.

Terminal command:

```
cp -R /home/user/directory /destination
```

You'll get it to work soon, just continue thinking hard. Me, it took about 3 hours before I understand the command.

Comment: this isn't really what OP wanted, they actually wanted to copy the contents, not the directory, although it wasn't clear from the question